# Gnome Ubuntu 17.04 and Nvidia issues

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, gnome

I have a desktop running a Geforce GT 1030 and I'm trying to make Ubuntu work on it.

To install, I had to edit the grub launcher to add `nomodeset`, after which the installation concluded smoothly. However, I still have to add `nomodeset` every time during boot to get it to work.

I tried purging nvidia drivers and installing the most recent version (384, I think) and it only made things worse (got stuck during boot and adding nomodeset changed nothing). So I formatted and did a clean install.

What to do to make this work?

Extra info: The monitor is plugged to the mobo, not to the card.

Comment: Disable Secure Boot in BIOS. Everything else is correct. But it is unclear wy monitor is not connected to the card.

Comment: Gpu has DVI-D + HDMI. Monitor has VGA + DVI-D, but only came with a VGA cable, so I was plugging it directly on the mobo VGA port while my DVI-D cable arrives.

Answer (score 0):

Make it permanent:

`sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`

Change:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`

To:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodeset quiet splash"`

`sudo update-grub`